# Media is not attached after import

Tags: plugins, multisite, attachments, media, import

I am new there and I need some help for importing a wordpress blog.

I have a old wordpress 3.1 blog (no multisites) and need to move to new hosting (a sites under multisites). I don't have the access of database so I do a wordpress export.

Then I do the wordpress import as usual, with `Download and import file attachments` checked. My hosting a restrictive hosting so I need to do break down the process by keep on reloading the import page (step 2). After all done I found only the last imported images are attached to the posts, all other linkages are gone.

Question:

- does it matter that the attachment linkage is gone?
- If I want to re-attach the attachment to the origin post, any plugin should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer by myself.

I finally get into update the attachment by myself. I found the default attachment UI is totally a pain, so I use [bulk change attachment parent](http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/bulk-change-attachment-parent/) to change the media id when I know the post id. (It is OK for about 50 images)

The only problem with that plugin is the bulk change part doesn't works under common sense. Will fire ticket later.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install and manage plugins on this site, install [wp-dbmanager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dbmanager/) - you can use this to export your full database.  If it will be living on the same URL, you can use the same plugin to import the DB for the new install.

Comment: sadly that url will be different...and since the site structure is not same, I think it is not a direct mapping.
I want a plugin/ importer can do the reattachment from the xml file, or allow me to attach by url, not search

Comment: If all that's changing is the base URL, follow the directions at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL to change the site URL.  Even if you change the permalink structure after the fact, it will still have the images and other assets attached to the proper post ID's.